# In Codename one combobox text is cut off

Tags: android, ios, combobox, codenameone

I have a number of drop-down comboboxes, which are populated from code.
The text (of the currently selected item) seem to be getting cut off a certian distance from the right side of the screen.
I tried setting the default item to include very long strings in the designer, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Here's what I'm seeing in the simulator:

[image: shot of issue from simulator]

Here is what the text should show:

[image: screenshot showing expanded dropdown]

It's slightly less pronounced on higher resolution devices, but is still an issue.

I'm also having difficulty getting rid of the blue button (which shows the name of the previous form)

Comment: It's about `Android` or `iOS` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I have this issue on both platforms, and also in the simulator

Answer (score 1):

Did you use a custom renderer?

I'm assuming you did, in that case make sure your renderer places the text in the top level component in the center of a border layout.

Also define a rendering prototype value as the longest possible value you can think of:

```
String longValue = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
cmb.setRenderingPrototype(longValue);
```

This is used to layout your renderer initially. If you used a custom renderer you need the long value to be of the renderer object e.g. `Map` etc.

Comment: I didn't use a custom renderer and I'd rather not if I can avoid it. 
I will try the rendering prototype and let you know if it fixes it.

Comment: Ok so I tried this (setRenderingPrototype), but I'm still having the same issue. are then any theme constants that could be causing me issues?

Comment: Did you set a large amount of side padding anywhere? It's the only thing I can think of.